# Is there anyway I can prove a snap account isn’t mine

Tags: account-security

My boyfriend thinks a Snapchat account is mine when it isn’t. Is there anyway I can prove this is not true if the owner of the account won’t message me back?

Comment: It's very hard to prove a negative. I don't believe there is any technical solution that you are capable of which would allow you to prove that the account is not yours, at least if it's inactive.

Answer (score -1):

You could use the [Snapchat API](https://developers.snapchat.com/ads/) to get the e-mail of the account and then verify that it isn't your account. You will need some programming skill for that.

Comment: I cant find the email

Comment: else i found this [article](https://www.quora.com/How-can-I-find-someones-email-that-they-used-for-Snapchat)

Comment: There’s no link

Comment: Hover over the word "article"

Comment: I think the update changed that. How would I use the API

Comment: I never worked with it before but it isn't different to other API's. There is a link provided in my answer to the Documentation.

Comment: Even if it was possible to determine the email address of the account using the API, how would @Moo97 prove that the email address didn't belong to her?  It's the fundamental problem of trying to prove a negative.  Moo97's problem is really a more an issue of trust.

Comment: @user52472 you are right